# How to sync files using sftp sync extension for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using this Visual Studio Code extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp

How does one command this sftp sync extension to sync local files, and directories containing them, to a web server?

In the sftp.json file I have:

```
  "uploadOnSave": false
```

because I need save my files before they are ready for upload. The only way I know to upload them when ready is to temporarily change the above to true and then save the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that the latest version of Visual Studio Code has updates that broke this extension. I am moving on to other FTP extensions for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Is it this one, the current fork, or another? https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for this extension [lists available commands](https://github.com/Natizyskunk/vscode-sftp/wiki/Commands), one of which is `SFTP: Upload Active File` (which can be issued from the VS Code command palette, which in turn can be opened via Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P)